# How to prevent hangfire recurring job execution after IIS restart?

Tags: c#, .net, hangfire

After we set Hangfire (v1.7.7) to [always run](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.html), all recurring jobs execute immediately after we restart IIS or recycle the pool. It's an undesirable behavior because we have jobs scheduled to run once a month or once a week and every deploy is making them run.

We couldn't find a configuration property in the documentation or forums to prevent this behavior and we're still analyzing the repo, trying to find a clue.

We found [this issue](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/620) and [this discussion](https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/how-to-stop-a-recurring-task-running-late-or-when-missed/3240) related to our problem.

Apart from the link provided above, which represents the exact configuration we made in order to make Hangfire always run, this is our current configuration:

```
private BackgroundJobServer _backgroundJobServer;
app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
{
    Authorization = new[] { new HangfireRestrictiveAuthorizationFilter() },
    StatsPollingInterval = UM_MINUTO_EM_MILISEGUNDOS * 10
});

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("Implanta", new SqlServerStorageOptions 
{ 
    CommandBatchMaxTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), 
    SchemaName = "HangFireSiscaf",
    SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = null
});

_backgroundJobServer = new BackgroundJobServer(new BackgroundJobServerOptions()
{
    Queues = new[] { "siscaf" },
    ServerName = "SISCAF.NET",
    WorkerCount = 5
});
```

And this is how we usually schedule our recurring jobs (a couple method names and strings are written in pt-BR):

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<ColetaMensalCFATask>(
    ColetaMensalCFATask.Key,
    x => x.ExecuteTask(),
    Cron.Monthly(diaAgendamentoMensalColetaCFA, timeSpanHoraAgendamentoMensalColetaCFA.Minutes),
    TimeZoneInfo.Local,
    "siscaf");
```

**UPDATE 1:**
We were able to reproduce the desired behavior by deleting the job execution history and adding every job as a new one. Not a satisfying solution though.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you need to change the behaviour within Hangfire you have to write a [JobFilter](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/extensibility/using-job-filters.html).

This class can implement various interfaces, but in your case you could probably implement the `IClientFilter` and check in `OnCreating()` if the job should be created or implement `IElectStateFilter` and check in `OnStateElection()` if the job should be enqueued.

Be aware that there are already a bunch of other job filters and that they are executed in a defined order, given by the integer value within the `Order` property. To ensure that your filter will be one of the last, set this maybe to `int.MaxValue`.

To apply this job filter to your job, you could either add the attribute to the method or class or if it should be executed for every job you can add an instance to the global list via `GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Add()` within your startup.

If you are within one of the filter methods, each of them has a `context` property, that has access to the monitoring api through the `Storage` property:

```
var monitor = context.Storage.GetMonitoringApi();
var jobDetails = monitor.JobDetails(context.BackgroundJob.Id);

foreach (var kvp in jobDetails.Properties)
{
    Trace.WriteLine($"{kvp.Key => kvp.Value}");
}

foreach (var entry in jobDetails.History.OrderBy(e => e.CreatedAt))
{
    Trace.WriteLine($"{entry.StateName} ({entry.CreatedAt}): {Reason}");

    foreach (var kvp in entry.Data)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine($"   {kvp.Key} => {kvp.Value}");
    }
}
```

Currently I can't check what they contain in case of a freshly created recurring job, but if you take a look at it with the debugger, you should find some information about the recurring job. One simple way to check this, is to take a look at the Hangfire Dashboard. If you open the job details page and find anything that links to the recurring job, than it is available through the monitoring API, cause all Hangfire Webpages use this API to get their content.

Just dug a little deeper and found the points to retrieve all information from the recurring job by a given job id:

```
var monitor = context.Storage.GetMonitoringApi();
var jobDetails = monitor.JobDetails(context.BackgroundJob.Id);

if(jobDetails.Properties.TryGetValue("RecurringJobId", out string recurringId))
{
    var values = context.Connection.GetAllEntriesFromHash($"recurring-job:{recurringId}");

    foreach (var kvp in values)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine($"{kvp.Key} => {kvp.Value}");
    }
}
```

Also the Enqueued state of a recurring job has always as reason the text `Triggered by recurring job scheduler`, which can be used as a filter like this:

```
    public void OnStateElection(ElectStateContext context)
    {
        switch (context.CandidateState)
        {
            case EnqueuedState enqueued when enqueued.Reason == "Triggered by recurring job scheduler":
                Trace.WriteLine($"Was triggered by job scheduler.");

                // Skip all jobs of job scheduler
                context.CandidateState = new SucceededState(null, 0, 0);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: We've tried to implement a JobFilter similar to [the one commented in the issue](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/620#issuecomment-466385193), when our jobs are scheduled Hangfire triggers them immediately and the property `context.InitialState` is `null`, meaning we can't identify the reason a job was triggered and therefore not able to cancel it's execution.